# Sorting Jekyll data files

Tags: yaml, jekyll

I run a Gaelic language site which has a list of uncommonly known vocabulary stored in a data file called `faclair.yml`.

The structure inside `faclair.yml` is as follows

```
- gd: "Gaelic word"
  url: "/gaelic-word/"
  ga: "Irish equivalent"
  gv: "Manx equivalent"
  en: "English equivalent"
```

I display this list on a Gaelic language page `gd.html` using the following:

```
{% for facal in site.data.faclair %}
    <p><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ facal.url }}">{{ facal.gd }}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

Because I've entered the Gaelic words into `faclair.yml` alphabetically, this page displays the words in alphabetical order by default.

I also want to display the lists on Irish, Manx and English language pages, so I have the following pages.

`ga.html`

```
{% for facal in site.data.faclair %}
    <p><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ facal.url }}">{{ facal.ga }}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

gv.html

```
{% for facal in site.data.faclair %}
    <p><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ facal.url }}">{{ facal.gv }}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

en.html

```
{% for facal in site.data.faclair %}
    <p><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ facal.url }}">{{ facal.en }}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to sort these lists on these pages alphabetically by the corresponding language as they currently appear unsorted due to them being displayed in the order they appear in `faclair.yml`.

Comment: Maybe you could use the sort filter like this `{{ site.data.faclair | sort: "gv" }}` combined with a fresh assignment before looping? (https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/)